# Getting shell command output in c++ before it ends running

Tags: c++, command-line, popen

Is there anyway to get the command stdout and stderr output before it ends running?
I've been trying `popen` and here's the code:

```
string exec(const char* cmd) {
    char buffer[128];
    string result;
    string modCmd = (string)cmd + (string)" 2>&1";
    FILE* pipe = popen(modCmd.c_str(), "r");
    if (!pipe) throw runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    try {
        while (!feof(pipe)) {
            if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != nullptr)
            {
                result += buffer;
                cout << buffer;
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {
        pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

but the problem is, all the `cout`s stack up and run after the command's running is over.
P.S. The command I'm trying to execute is aria2c

Comment: [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)?

Comment: Most likely application that you are running buffers all the output. There is no workaround for this on your side of the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was as mentioned by [@VTT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7860670/vtt) that aria2c doesn't flush it's output, but there's a workaround which is running `stdbuf -o0 aria2c` instead of running `aria2c ...`